# reference page some numbering is coming

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I have used

```
\def\thebibliography#1{\section{References}%
    \markboth{References}{References}
    \list{[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin
    \labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
```

and  for referencing at the end I have used

```
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\end{thebibliography}
```

now in the pdf I am getting `$4.2$` Reference..why this number `$4.2$` is coming in the reference page as well as in the table of contents ?

I dont want it..

[image: mmmd]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{Ex}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth{\mylength}{\scriptsize Lem.\ 1.1(ii)} 
\newcommand\myeq[1]{\stackrel{\makebox[\mylength]{\scriptsize #1}}{=}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rank}{Rank}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0}
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\clearpage
\def\thebibliography#1{\section{References}%
    \markboth{References}{References}
  \list{[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin
\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please don't post such fragments only

Comment: You want `\section*{References}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}`. By the way, in the title of [1], it should be `$\lambda Tx+Sx$` rather than `$\lambda$Tx+ Sx`

Answer (score 3):

Your `bibliography` environment uses

```
\section{References}
```

which sets a section *with* numbering. If you don't want that, then use

```
\section*{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}References}
```

Based on the (re)definition of `thebibliograhy`, the headers should be set correctly to `References` (via `\markboth`).

The addition of `\protect\numberline{}` ensures that the alignment of your `\section` titles in the ToC is correct - numbered or unnumbered sections. If you drop it, the `References` title will be flush left with the other (numbered) elements.

Comment: I am not understanding , please help

Comment: @Urgent: Change `\section{References}` to `\section*{References}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}References}` in your definition of `thebibliography`.

Comment: it is not coming stillll

Comment: @Urgent: What is not coming? What does your `\def\thebibliography` look like now?

Comment: \def\thebibliography#1{\section*{References}\addcontentsline{toc}      {section}{\protect‌​\numberline{}Referen‌​ces}%
    \markboth{References}{References}
  \list{[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin
\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

Comment: @Urgent: Ok. So with that definition what "is not coming still"? I thought you *don't* want numbers.

Comment: after writing this, and compiling..error is coming

Comment: @Urgent: It would be great if you could supply the community with something that replicates your current problem. This "something" I'm talking about is called a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764). It is code that starts with `\documentclass` (you've provided this) and ends with `\end{document}` in such a way that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly when you're seeing (you haven't provided this). Without it, I cannot adequately replicate your issue.